# hello this is the test case and i have to pass n number of arguments in function

Tags: javascript, function

hello this is the test case and i have to pass n number of arguments in function('you should be    able to use arguments',

```
    function () {   
        var a = Math.random(),    
           b = Math.random(),   
           c = Math.random(),  
             d = Math.random(); 
           expect(answers.useArguments(a)).to.eql(a);    
   expect(answers.useArguments(a, b)).to.eql(a + b);      
 expect(answers.useArguments(a, b, c)).to.eql(a + b + c);      
 expect(answers.useArguments(a, b, c, d)).to.eql(a + b + c + d);   
      });
```

so in function what i have to write asi i write this

```
return Array.prototype.call(arguments,function(a,b)                                         {         
      for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++)                  {   
                   return a+b;                
  }          
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is function to sum it's arguments:

```
function sum() {
    var result = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        result += arguments[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

or using reduce:

```
function sum() {
    return [].slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(a,b) {
        return a+b;
    });
}
```